# Data Type Qualifiers Definition PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I go about defining a table with a language specific (qualified) attribute?

For example:

```
ID| object |description (english)|description (french)| size | color (english) | color (french)
```

in the above example we have 3 'normal' fields and 2 language qualified fields : description and color.

What is best practice for defining these type of fields within one table?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this.  But a method for your specific data is to have another table with one row per language.  Such as table would have:

- objectLanguageId (serial column to identify the row)
- objectId (reference to a table with one row per object)
- language
- description
- color

Then the "object" table would have

- objectId
- objectName
- size

Note:  This is definitely not the only approach.  If you need everything in your system translated, then you want a more sophisticated and generic mechanism.  You may also need to take into account things like French sizes are different from sizes in other countries -- even countries that speak the same language.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you